# Cannot split equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

I do not seem to be able to split this very long equation. I've tried `multline`, `align`, `dmath`, `split` and a few other possibilities but none of them have worked; it might be a stupid mistake, but I can't find it. (New to LaTeX)

```
\begin{equation}
W = \int_{k<\Lambda} [Dg][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \exp{\Biggl\{ i \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \Biggl[\frac{m_{p}^{2}}{2}R - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu} + i\bar{\psi}^i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi^i + \Bigl(\bar{\psi}_{L}^{i} V_{ij} \Phi \psi_{R}^{j} + h.c. \Bigr) - |D_{\mu}\Phi|^2 - V(\Phi)\Biggr] \Biggr\}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Hint: If you make your snippets compilable, the helpers can act faster. `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as understand question, you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

     \begin{document}
\begin{multline}
W = \int_{k<\Lambda} [Dg][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \exp\biggl\{ i \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \biggl[\frac{m_{p}^{2}}{2}R- \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu}\\
%
\qquad + i\bar{\psi}^i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi^i + \bigl(\bar{\psi}_{L}^{i} V_{ij} \Phi \psi_{R}^{j} + h.c. \bigr) - |D_{\mu}\Phi|^2 - V(\Phi)\biggr] \biggr\}
\end{multline}
   \end{document}
```

Reason, why you receive errors in your effort to split equations, is use `\left` ... `\right` parenthesis, as explained @Przemysław Scherwentke in his answer.

**Edit:** As suggested @egreg, with `\bigg` size of parenthesis the equation looks nicer.

**Edit (2):** To vertical centering of equation number can be obtain width `mathtolls` package environment `multilined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
W = \int_{k<\Lambda} [Dg][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \exp\biggl\{i \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \biggl[\frac{m_{p}^{2}}{2}R- \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu} \\
%
\qquad + i\bar{\psi}^i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi^i + \bigl(\bar{\psi}_{L}^{i} V_{ij} \Phi \psi_{R}^{j} + h.c. \Bigr) - |D_{\mu}\Phi|^2 - V(\Phi)\biggr] \biggr\}
\end{multlined}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest `\bigg` size

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of splitting. The source of mistake in tries of `align` etc. was `{` after `\exp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}

%\begin{equation}
%W = \int_{k<\Lambda} [Dg][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \exp{\Biggl\{ i \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \Biggl[\frac{m_{p}^{2}}{2}R - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu} + i\bar{\psi}^i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi^i + \Bigl(\bar{\psi}_{L}^{i} V_{ij} \Phi \psi_{R}^{j} + h.c. \Bigr) - |D_{\mu}\Phi|^2 - V(\Phi)\Biggr] \Biggr\}}
%\end{equation}
\begin{align}
W &= \int_{k<\Lambda} [Dg][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \exp\Biggl\{ i \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \Biggl[\frac{m_{p}^{2}}{2}R- \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu}\notag\\
&\qquad + i\bar{\psi}^i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi^i + \Bigl(\bar{\psi}_{L}^{i} V_{ij} \Phi \psi_{R}^{j} + h.c. \Bigr) - |D_{\mu}\Phi|^2 - V(\Phi)\Biggr] \Biggr\}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
W &= \int_{k<\Lambda} [Dg][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \exp\biggl\{ i \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \biggl[\frac{m_{p}^{2}}{2}R- \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu}\notag\\
&\qquad + i\bar{\psi}^i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi^i + \Bigl(\bar{\psi}_{L}^{i} V_{ij} \Phi \psi_{R}^{j} + \mathrm{h.c.} \Bigr) - |D_{\mu}\Phi|^2 - V(\Phi)\biggr] \biggr\}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would recommend the second version, with `\biggl` and `\mathrm{h.c.}`.

Comment: One doesn't really want each line to be numbered here though, would one?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh, yes. Adding `\notag`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment.

I would also like to suggest that you use `\int\limits` instead of "just" `\int` for the first integral symbol. That way, the limit of integration is set *below* the integral symbol, making the whole expression more compact. For increased legibility/parsability, one could add a thin-space, `\,`, after `\sqrt{-g}` and before the large opening square bracket. See the code below for an implementation of these ideas.

Finally, do note that `\exp` is a math operator and does *not* take an argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "split" environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
W &= \int\limits_{k<\Lambda} [Dg][DA][D\psi][D\Phi] \exp\biggl\{ i \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \,\biggl[\frac{m_{p}^{2}}{2}R - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu} \\
&\qquad + i\bar{\psi}^i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi^i + \Bigl(\bar{\psi}_{L}^{i} V_{ij} \Phi \psi_{R}^{j} + h.c. \Bigr) - |D_{\mu}\Phi|^2 - V(\Phi)\biggr] \biggr\}
\end{split}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```